# Linear independence of polynomials over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Determine whether the polynomials $x^2 − 1, x^2 − 4$ and $x^2 − 9$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

My attempt:

I have to see if I can find rational numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a(x^2 − 1) + b(x^2 − 4) + c(x^2 − 9) = 0$. If $a=b=c=0$, then $x^2 − 1, x^2 − 4$ and $x^2 − 9$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.
If $a,b,c$ are not all zero, then $x^2 − 1, x^2 − 4$ and $x^2 − 9$ are not linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$.

$a(x^2 − 1) + b(x^2 − 4) + c(x^2 − 9) = 0$

$x^2(a+b+c)-a-4b-9c = 0$

$a+b+c = 0$

$-a-4b-9c = 0$

Then, $a=5c/3$, and $b=-8c/3$.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: For example, take $c=3$, and you get a nontrivial combination of those polynomials which vanishes, so they are linearly dependent

Comment: For an alternative (and maybe quicker) approach: take the linear subspace $\mathbb{Q}_{2}[X]$ of polynomials with degree less or equal to 2. It is a 3-dimensional subspace which contains $f=x^{2}-1$,$g=x^{2}-4$ and $h=x^{2}-9$. If $f,g,h$ are independent, they must span $\mathbb{Q}_{2}[X]$, which is clearly impossible since $x$ cannot be written as a linear combination of $f,g,h$

Answer (score 2):

From where you’ve reached in your solution you proceed with the concluding statement:

$\forall c \ne 0 \exists a=\frac{5c}{3}, b=\frac{-8c}{3}:a(x^2-1)+b(x^2-4)+c(x^2-9)=0\Rightarrow$ the polynomials are linearly dependent $(\therefore)$